# Cannot extract jar file in java application packaged for windows

Tags: java, netbeans, jar, packaging, extract

My program was created in Netbeans 8.0.2. The program is supposed to create a (database) folder after installation and extract the contents of a (database) jar file from its library. The folder gets created quite okay, but the contents of the jar file do not get extracted.
How can I get the extraction of the jar file to work?
NB: When I run the program in Netbeans, everything goes well.

Sample Code:

```
    String appHomeDir = new java.io.File(".").getCanonicalPath();
    String destDir = appHomeDir + "/database";
    File folder = new File(destDir);
    if (!folder.exists()) {
    folder.mkdir();
    String current = new java.io.File(".").getCanonicalPath();
    String jarFile = current + "\\app\\lib\\database.jar";
    java.util.jar.JarFile jar = new java.util.jar.JarFile(jarFile);
    java.util.Enumeration enumEntries = jar.entries();
    while (enumEntries.hasMoreElements()) {
    java.util.jar.JarEntry file = (java.util.jar.JarEntry) enumEntries.nextElement();
    java.io.File f = new java.io.File(destDir + java.io.File.separator + file.getName());
    if (file.isDirectory()) { // if its a directory, create it
    f.mkdir();
    continue;
    }
    java.io.InputStream is = jar.getInputStream(file); // get the input stream
    java.io.FileOutputStream fos = new java.io.FileOutputStream(f);
    while (is.available() > 0) {  // write contents of 'is' to 'fos'
    fos.write(is.read());
    }
    fos.close();
    is.close();
    }
    }
```

So the "database" directory gets created but the contents of "database.jar" do not get extracted.

Comment: Watch out for the working directly, from where do you ran the application?

Comment: @omer727, I don't get your question. Do you mean the working directory  of the application? If so, it runs from: c:\users\someuser\AppData\Local\MySoftware. I am using windows 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved: I replaced "/app/lib/database.jar" with "/lib/database.jar"